# cpufreq: cpu frequency going down to minimum just when I need extra power

Tags: lenovo, cpu, cpu-load, cpufreq, frequency

I've spent almost 3 days around this problem, to no avail.

I felt the laptop was running slow on certain tasks, slower than usual so I downloaded [cpufreq](http://konkor.github.io/cpufreq/about/) extension to try and monitor and maybe directly control the CPU running frequency and power consumption.

**The problem** is that I always see the CPU frequency drop to a minimal value (either 800MHz or 400MHz) on all 8 cores for no apparent reason. this seems to happen just when I need extra power- running code projects locally, opening several browser tabs etc.

I'm using `cpufreq` gnome shell extension to try and manually control the values, but this does not seem to help. no matter the changes, before and after reboots, the problem seems to appear out of nowhere, and disappear as well.

---

Things I've tried after researching online, but didn't help:

- By default the `intel_pstate` driver was used, but I disabled it (by editing `/etc/default/grub`), and now using `acpi driver`
- tried using `CPU Power Manager` gnome shell extension as well to control the power/speed programmatically
- in `cpufreq` extension, I've tried every min-max frequency combination I can think of, as well as switch between governor programs, and enable/disable `frequency boost`
- I tried settings the max frequency directly for ALL 8 cores, and disable ppc like this:

-- `echo 1 | sudo dd of=/sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc`

-- `echo 2900000 | sudo dd of=/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq`

---

**Any ideas going forward?** I really dont know what to do. this prevents me from working, as most code-developing tasks I do require some horsepower. even scrolling a text editor up and down becomes a pain on 400MHz, while several other things are running in the background.

Here's a random screenshot from `cpufreq` with some more technical details:
[image: cpufreq and system details]

Here is the relevant BIOS settings:
[image: BIOS power mgmt settings]

Comment: In addition to the cpu power governor, check for thermal throttling and power throttling, especially if you have cpu power saving disabled and are seeing performance dips immediately after a heavy load runs for a bit.

Comment: Your TDP is only 15 watts. Your CPU is throttling down, and your screenshot even says as much. To get the most out of your computer, you will have to do a bunch of tests to determine if you can safely turn up TDP somewhat, or if it is already temperature limited as @user10489 mentioned. Suggest you use turbostat (linux-tools-common) to monitor stuff and to go back to the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver. You can use passive and disable HWP if you want.

Comment: Thank you both, but I dont think I'm sure what I can check/change next. I uploaded another screenshot, of the BIOS settings for power mgmt. any suggestions on how to edit these? any other benchmarks or info I can provide?

Comment: I also reverted everything I already did, installed cpupower and try to manually set min/max freq using (cpupower frequency-set). things are better- but still the problem exists..

Comment: As to what else you can do-- turn up fan speed?  Clean the fans?  Stop blocking the fan outlets by using it on the bed? :)  Buy hardware with better TDP / airflow...

Answer (score 0):

**You can set the CPU to maximum speed using this bash script:**

*Make a file called cpumaxspeed.sh and enter in this code:*

```
#!/bin/bash
#Getting and setting variables

echo Getting info....

CPUMIN=$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq)
CPUMAX=$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq)
CPUMAXGHZ=$(echo "scale=1; $CPUMAX / 1000000" | bc)
CPUMINGHZ=$(echo "scale=1; $CPUMIN / 1000000" | bc)

#Display min and max CPU frequency in MHz
echo CPU min frequency: $CPUMIN" MHz" / $CPUMINGHZ" GHz"
echo CPU max frequency: $CPUMAX" MHz" / $CPUMAXGHZ" GHz"

#Setting CPU governor
echo Setting governor to performance
sudo cpufreq-set -r -g performance
echo Set governor to performance

#Setting to max frequency
echo Setting CPU frequency to be $CPUMAX" MHz" / $CPUMAXGHZ" GHz"
sudo cpufreq-set -r -f $CPUMAXGHZ"GHz"
echo Set CPU frequency to $CPUMAXGHZ"GHz"

done
```

Execute it with this command:

```
sudo sh cpumaxspeed.sh
```